# Chrome hover effect sticking on rounded corners

Tags: html, css, image, border, styling

I have an image within a container. The container has rounded corners in order to make the child image circular.
There's a hover effect on the parent, but in Chrome (but not Firefox!) the effect remains when the cursor leaves the image.

**Expected (Firefox):**
[image]

**Actual (Chrome):**
[image]

Please see my demo code below:

```css
.user {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.image-container {
    background: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding-left: 0%;
}

.image-container:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.image-container:hover .user {
    opacity: 0.3;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/16269580?v=4" class="user">
</div>
```

I'm looking to have the hover effect end immediately on leaving the "circle". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So the mouse needs to leave the complete div in chrome

Comment: @mplungjan yes, that's the issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `border-radius` to image class `.user` too:

```css
.user {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.image-container {
    background: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding-left: 0%;
}

.image-container:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.image-container:hover .user {
    opacity: 0.3;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/16269580?v=4" class="user">
</div>
```